# How to get the Address ( Street, City, Country) details from user IP Address on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have developed a simple registraton form using `VisualForce Page` and given users access to this `Page` through a `Force.com Site`. The controller stores the visiting user's IP Address. How can I get their physical address (Street, City, Country) from this IP Address?

Answer (score 5):

> Update: This solution is based on the available IP address of the user. Generally this IP is ISP's IP and when you find the location it will be ISP's physical location. To get more accurate result refer to the updated solution below.

You have the IP address in your Apex class. You can make a http callout to get the address details with the below code. Hope this helps.

Don't forget to add http://ipinfo.io in Set Up > Administer > Security Controls > Remote Site Settings.

```
String strCity;
String strRegion;
String strCountry;
String strPostal;
Http httpProtocol = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
String userIPAddress = '8.7.228.252';//Assign user IP address here
String endpoint = 'http://ipinfo.io/'+userIPAddress+'/json';
request.setEndPoint(endpoint);
request.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse response = httpProtocol.send(request);
System.debug(response.getBody());
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(response.getBody());
while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
    if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'city')) {
        parser.nextToken();
        strCity = parser.getText();
    }
    if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'region')) {
        parser.nextToken();
        strRegion = parser.getText();
    }
    if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'country')) {
        parser.nextToken();
        strCountry = parser.getText();
    }
    if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'postal')) {
        parser.nextToken();
        strPostal = parser.getText();
    }   
}
System.debug('strCity = '+strCity);
System.debug('strRegion = '+strRegion);
System.debug('strCountry = '+strCountry);
System.debug('strPostal = '+strPostal);
```

**Updated solution**

In this solution I have used Geolocation API supported by most of the modern browser. The downside of this solution is that the position is not available unless the user approves it. Once approved, we can send the exact address to controller for further  use.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="NavigatorLocation">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script> 
    <apex:form id="myForm">
        <apex:outputPanel id="addressDetails">
            Street Address : {!street_number}<br/>
            route : {!route}<br/>
            city : {!city}<br/>
            state : {!state}<br/>
            zip_code {!zip_code}<br/>
        </apex:outputPanel> 
        <apex:inputHidden value="{!street_number}" id="street_number"/>
        <apex:inputHidden value="{!route}" id="route"/>
        <apex:inputHidden value="{!city}" id="city"/>
        <apex:inputHidden value="{!state}" id="state"/>
        <apex:inputHidden value="{!zip_code}" id="zip_code"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save" reRender="addressDetails"/>
    </apex:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lat = 0;
        var long = 0;
        var geocoder;

        function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        }
        function getAddress() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    lng = position.coords.longitude;
                    console.log('alert 1: ' + lat + ', ' + lng);
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            console.log(results);
                            var arrAddress = results[0].address_components;
                            for (ac = 0; ac < arrAddress.length; ac++) {
                                if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "street_number") { document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.street_number}').value = arrAddress[ac].long_name; }
                                if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "route") { document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.route}').value = arrAddress[ac].short_name;}
                                if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "locality") {document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.city}').value = arrAddress[ac].long_name;}
                                if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "administrative_area_level_1") {document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.state}').value = arrAddress[ac].short_name; }
                                if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "postal_code") { document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.zip_code}').value = arrAddress[ac].long_name; }
                            }
                        }else{
                            console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                        }
                    });
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log('ERROR(' + error.code + '): ' + error.message);
                });
            } else {
                console.log('geolocation is unsupported');
            }
        }
        window.onload=function(){ 
            initialize();
            getAddress(); 
        };
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class NavigatorLocation {
    public String street_number {get;set;}
    public String route {get;set;}
    public String city {get;set;}
    public String state {get;set;}
    public String zip_code {get;set;}
    public NavigatorLocation() {

    }
    public void Save() {
        System.debug('street_number : '+street_number);
        System.debug('route : '+ route);
        System.debug('city : '+ city);
        System.debug('state : '+state);
        System.debug('zip_code : '+zip_code);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Saroj Bera, Thank You for your response. it's working fine but i am getting the service provider address details. ex: user a located x city , he using y city internet. i am getting the y city details but i need to get the x city details. Please let me know how to acheive this. thanks, suman

Comment: @Murali Yes you can do that using Geolocation API but user has to allow location access. Please refer to my updated solution above. Apart from this I don't think you can get the exact address of the user.

Comment: @SarojBera How would I post this data to the controller on page load instead of clicking the save button?

Comment: Hai Suman Murali, I am also facing same issue. ex: User located in X city means how to get the Xcity records/data based on user system IP address

Comment: @Sfdcprog You can't rely on the IP address for the exact location of the user. If the user is inside and corporate network or using a VPN it will give you the ISP's location not the user's exact location.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [this](https://gist.github.com/abbas133/ba561b60d8ed05f7004f) helpful.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Client side IP geolocation using <a href="http://ipinfo.io">ipinfo.io</a></h3>

        <hr/>
        <div id="ip"></div>
        <div id="address"></div>
        <hr/>Full response: <pre id="details"></pre>
        <input type="text" value="" id="city" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
            $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
            $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
            $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
            $("#city").html(response.city);
            document.getElementById('city').value = response.city;
        }, "jsonp");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What this snippet basically does is, taking the IP address and giving back the information like address and city.
It uses the library from [IP-Info](https://ipinfo.io/). Read their documentation for more help.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi Abbas, Thanks for your response. Please let me know how can use this code in trigger or apex class.

Comment: i used html code but i am getting the wrong address details, present i am chennai but result showing mumbai. please see the response below. Full response:

{
    "ip": "",
    "hostname": "No Hostname",
    "city": "Mumbai",
    "region": "Maharashtra",
    "country": "IN",
    "loc": ",
    "org": "AS18101 Reliance Communications Ltd.DAKC MUMBAI"

Comment: That response depends on the service provider, you can try searching co-ordinates on google map and getting correct city name.

Comment: ok, thanks. Please let me know how can i use html code in trigger or apex class. i need to write the trigger on contact object, the objective of this trigger is get address information from ip addres whenever contact record created or updated. please let me know how we can achieve this requirment.

Comment: You cannot use HTML code in trigger or apex class.

Comment: yes, how can achieve this requirment through trigger or apex class.?

Comment: Your trigger would need to call async apex (queueable/batch/future) to perform the callout. Why not have the VF page do it, though, so the user can correct any inaccuracies?

Comment: Hi Mike Chale,  in registration page have only email address input field, if user fills the email and click on submit button we are storing email address on custom object, here we are getting the ip adddress of visit user but we need city or state details of user using for another application. how we can achieve this req. pleae let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @Abbas, you've posted what we call a "link only" answer that some might say "is not an answer". It's preferred you provide some details from the link, giving credit to the author, should the link ever disappear. If you will, please update your answer with more information.

Comment: @crmprogdev The link is for my private gist and this was the thing that I did some time back for some POC. Sorry for having it this way, updating the answer